# Do keyservers keep logs of who adds whom to their keyrings?

Tags: tls, privacy, pgp

Maybe it depends on the keyserver. Does that pose privacy issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot tell whether the keyserver operator logs access to his keyserver or not. Most common keyserver software is open source and can easily be changed (if logging features aren't built-in anyway).

However, it is **not possible to trace which key ID** / user interacted with the keyserver (the clients do not authenticate in any fashion), but keyserver operators ***could* log their user's IP addresses**.

Answer (score 0):

As for *adding a keyserver to a keyring*, you have to store his *public certificate* in your own keyring, and as a *public certificate* is **fully** shareable, there is no way to trace each copy of a public certificate.

So the answer is clearly no.

As all this stuff is public and the only thing you do is to store (or not to store)
this in a speficic personal directorie, you'll be able to drop them whenever you want.

The only issue may be if you sign them as a trusted third party (authority).
In this case you may have to *revoke* your self signing.

Comment: What about access to your directory structure, for example your /home/username? Wouldn't that be accessed when you save the key?

Comment: No. Your ssl library will only use one specific directory to store certificats. No other kind of browsing/sharing.

Comment: Ok. what directory? And is username revealed to the keyserver? I'd expect if the directory is subdir of your home, than yes, unless the key is downloaded to `/tmp` and then moved to that directory.

Comment: Normaly no, I could speak about what I know: GnuPG (GNU open-source pgp solution) use `~/.gnupg/options` for configuration file and `~/.gnupg` as private dir, so there is no username in configuration nor in command line (`~` is an alias for `$HOME`, but resolved by `shell`, from `/etc/passwd` file).